# Array Push Overwrite

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

A record has an old color/number and new properties, which can be changed. I want to loop through an array and check to see if the old and new values don't match. If they don't, I'd like to determine which property was changed (color/number), set that record's changed property, and push it to an array. If the record has changes for both color and number, I want a copy of each array entry with the different changed property.

I've tried a few different ways and the push is overwriting the changed property, no matter what I do. I've tried to use a local array and that didn't work out either. Here is an example.

```
 export class Record {
 id: string;
 oldcolor: string;
 newcolor: string;
 oldnumber: string;
 newnumber: string;
 changed: string;
}




@Input() newrecords: Record[];
output: Record[] = [];

functionTest() {

    for (let rec of this.newrecords) {


            if (rec.newcolor != rec.oldcolor) {

                rec.changed  = "color";
                output.push(rec);


        }

            if (rec.newnumber != rec.oldnumber) {

                rec.changed = "number";
                output.push(rec);

            }


        }
    }


desired result
[{
 id: 1;
 oldcolor: red;
 newcolor: red;
 oldnumber: 6;
 newnumber: 6;
 changed: color;
},
{
 id: 1;
 oldcolor: red;
 newcolor: red;
 oldnumber: 6;
 newnumber: 6;
 changed: number;
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `output.push('rec')` it does not place a *copy of* `rec` in the array; it places `rec` (or, more precisely, a reference to `rec`) in the array.

So in the case where both properties have changed, you set `rec.changed` to "color", then put a reference to `rec` in the array, then set `rec.changed` to "number", then put another reference to `rec` in the array.  Everything is being done to a single object instance.

What you meant to do was have two objects, each with the same `id`, `oldColor`, `newColor`, `oldNumber`, and `newNumber`; but with different `changed` values.  (Whether that's the most efficient approach may be open to debate, but that's what you've described as the desired outcome.)  To do that, at some point you must make a copy of `rec`.

One way to do this (using vanilla javascript):

```
var copy = {
    id: rec.id,
    oldColor: rec.oldColor,
    newColor: rec.newColor,
    oldNumber: rec.oldNumber,
    newNumber: rec.newNumber,
    changed: rec.changed
}
```

You could do this before every push (and then `push(copy)` instead of `push(rec)`); or if that creates too many unneeded copies you could specifically see when you need two instances and make a copy only then.

Comment: Thanks Mark, that worked. What are some of the more efficient ways that you mentioned?

Comment: Well, really just speculating I guess... it depends what you're doing with the array once you've created it.  If you're feeding, say, the data store for a UI grid that needs to show the data a particular way, then there may be no other way about it.  OTOH if you're passing this for processing into a function you control, and could therefore define the structure any way you like, then for example having a value for `changed = 'both'`; or allowing the value of `changed` to be an array (`changed: ["color", "number"]`) could save processing (to copy objects) and memory (to store the copies).